# How you felt when you got this toy? The moment or when I had it?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Explain how you felt when you got this toy?

This could be a question in an English oral test.

Is it asking how I felt in the first few days after I got the toy or in the period of time when I had the toy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is asking how receiving the toy made you feel.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is asking for your "first reaction" at the moment you took possession of the toy (the use of "got" here could mean either a gift or a purchase).  So yes, it could be referring to the first few days, or even the first few minutes.  The fact that it is asking for "how you felt" is why I think it's asking for your initial reaction.

Answer (score 1):

[When](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/when) means **at the time at which**, so the question is asking how you felt at the moment you received the toy. You could get the same meaning using **on**:

> Explain how you felt **on getting** this toy

If you wanted to ask about somebody's feelings in the period after the event, you would change the conjunction to **after**.

> Explain how you felt **after** you got this toy

If you wanted to restrict the time, you could say **immediately after** or **in the days after**.

If you were interested in long-term or permanent changes in feelings, you would use **since** or **ever since**.

Note that **explain** is not a question-word: it's an instruction, so the sentence does not need a question mark.